# CastleWindsor, registering all classes in assembly coming from a common interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, castle-windsor

I have the following scenario of nested class and interfaces:

```
internal class ComplaintDeletedAuditSubscriber : BaseDeletedEventAuditHandler<Complaint, DeletedEvent>
{
...
}

internal abstract class BaseDeletedEventAuditHandler<TEntity, TEvent> : BaseEventAuditHandler<TEntity, TEvent>{
...
}

internal abstract class BaseEventAuditHandler<TEntity, TEvent> : EventNatsSubscriberBase<TEvent>
{
...
}

internal abstract class EventNatsSubscriberBase<T> : INatsSubscriber where T : BaseEvent
{
...
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is registering in my IoC container all classes (subscribers) that implement **INatsSubscriber**. As you can see **INatsSubscriber** is the main root and some levels below, actually at the last level, you can find **ComplaintDeletedAuditSubscriber** which is the class I mainly want to be registered.. and likewise many other similar subscribers. What I tried to do is:

```
Classes.FromThisAssembly()
     .BasedOn<INatsSubscriber>()
     .WithService.FromInterface()
     .LifestyleSingleton(),
```

and several other tries of course.. but none of my subscribers gets injected. What is the correct way of grabbing from the assembly the classes that implement **INatsSubscriber**? thanks in advance!

Edit: forgot to mention that I would like to inject all these classes as an IEnumerable.. to give an example:

```
public QueueListener(IEnumerable<INatsSubscriber> subscribers)
    {
        _subscribers = subscribers;
    }
```

in this case **subscribers** should be all those classes registered in the IoC container that imlpement INatsSubscriber

Answer (score 0):

You need `WithServiceBase()` instead of `FromInterface()`.

[The documentation has a good overview](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-by-conventions.md) of what each option does.